# React.js: project is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a simple React.js project. The project can be found [here](http://codepen.io/skosterin88/pen/PZayOG).
The HTML is as follows:

```
<header>
  <div class="container-center">
    <h1 class="text-center">Markdown Previewer</h1>
  </div>
</header>


  <div class="container-center" id="main-container">
  </div>


<footer>
  <div class="container-center">
    <p class="text-center">Copyright &copy; Sergey Kosterin, 2016. All rights reserved.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

The Javascript code is as follows:

```
var RawTextContainer = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <h1>Raw Text</h1>
    );
  }
});

var MarkdownContainer = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <h1>Markdown Text</h1>
    );
  }
});

var MainAppContainer = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <RawTextContainer />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <MarkdownContainer />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(<MainAppContainer />, document.getElementById('main-container'));
```

I want the app to show me two columns containing some text. But I don't see anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*React* doesnt use `class` keyword. Instead of that it should be `className`. [***Here***](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-I-have-to-use-className-instead-of-class-in-ReactJs-components-done-in-JSX) is a useful link about `class & className` keywords.

```
var MainAppContainer = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div className="row">  // className instead of class
        <div className="col-md-6"> // className instead of class
          <RawTextContainer />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6"> // className instead of class
          <MarkdownContainer />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

If it isn't the answer, then you have to provide a bit more information about your problem e.g. stack trace, errors etc. It's quite difficult to guess where is your problem.

***Update***

Worked example -> [Pen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGqwYM) i don't know why, but *Pen* doesnt recognise `ReactDOM` or you didn't include it. You can try to render your component through `React`.

```
React.render(<MainAppContainer/>, document...)
```

Also if you open browser console, you will get more information about some errors, or required statements (in your case jQuery isn't included file).

Thanks.

Comment: class is not the case, no content is displayed, although your point is important

Comment: @The, I used `className` but it didn't help. As for "more information" - when I open this project in the browser, the console shows no errors. I tried to paste the 100% working code from my other pen (see [here](http://codepen.io/skosterin88/pen/eJxgEW)) to see whether it would work but it didn't. I have a strong feeling that the app doesn't see React at all, although I added links to React and React-DOM in project settings.

Comment: @SergeyKosterin have you got any errors in console?

Comment: To all: I figured out what the point was. I provided an incorrect link to React-DOM. I changed it and the project worked as needed. @The, you were right - I should check errors in browser console.

Comment: You should also include jQuery, as it is Bootstrap dependency